# Is wordpress.com servers sending incorrect headers?

Tags: wordpress, asp-classic, wordpress.com

We are currently having big problems with all wordpress.com servers returning invalid data. This is probably related to the servers returning incorrect HTTP-headers.

This error is easy to reproduce by using the following VB/ASP code:

```
Set http = Server.CreateObject("Msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0")
http.Open "GET", "http://www.wordpress.com", False
http.Send
```

The error message will be:

msxml6.dll error '80072f78':
The server returned an invalid or unrecognized response

Any insights?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution is to set a user agent:

```
http.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0+(compatible;+MSIE+7.0;+Windows+NT+5.1)"
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue.
I solved it by doing the following:

`Set xml2 = Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.4.0")
 xml2.Open "POST", "http://wordpress.com/feed/", False
 xml2.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0+(compatible;+MSIE+7.0;+Windows+NT+5.1)"
 xml2.setOption 2, 13056
 xml2.Send`

After setting the User-Agent header I got a "The certificate authority is invalid or incorrect" error which was resolved with the SetOption command.

Comment: I found that extra code to ignore SSL errors was required as well, and some other code I found had the `setOption` before the `Open` which didn't work, it has to be after like your example.